# Is it true or false that every Lebesgue measurable set of a finite measure is contained in a Borel set of the same measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it true or false that every Lebesgue measurable set of a finite measure is contained in a Borel set of the same measure?

I would say that a G_delta set is a countable intersection of an open set, but and so it is a Borel set, but I'm not sure if this is makes the statement true?

Comment: The difference between the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is that the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is complete, meaning that every subset of a null-set is measurable.  This can eventually be boiled down to the fact that if a set $E$ is Lebesgue measureable but not Borel measurable, then $E$ must be the union of a Borel set, and a Lebesgue null set.

Comment: Ahhhh...so then the statement is true?

Comment: Your idea is correct. For each Lebesgue mearuable set $E$, you can find a $G_{\delta}$-set $G$ such that $E \subseteq G$ and $|G\setminus E| = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true. If $A$ is measurable then for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $U$ open so that $U\supset A$ and $\mu(U\backslash A) < \epsilon$. Then you take some intersection of $U_n$ like you pointed out.

Working with the complement, you see that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $F\subset A$, $F$ closed, so that $\mu(A\backslash F) < \epsilon$. 
If $\mu(A)$ is finite ( in particular, if $A$ is bounded), $F$ can be taken compact.